# Row number skipping in Excel generated using Dynamic Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, dynamic-reports

Generating excel using Dynamic reports, but for some reports the excel row numbers are not continues like 4,6,8...

Here is my code.

```
JasperXlsxExporterBuilder xlsxExporter  =  new ExporterBuilders().xlsxExporter(file).setDetectCellType(true).setIgnorePageMargins(true)
                .setWhitePageBackground(false).setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true).setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true).setCollapseRowSpan(false);


report.toXlsx(xlsxExporter);
```

Here is the excel

[image]

You can see the row number is not continues, its like 72,74,76.. its should be 72,73,74

Answer (score 0):

This *always* depends on the template / jrxml file.

When there is only a one pixel space between cells, the exporter will generate two rows.

Why?

Because Jasper exports pixel perfect reports. So if there is any space in between the rows, it will be exported.

This one pixel space could be in the groups header, footer, in the detail row, etc. pp.